# bower install - Cannot find module 'q'

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I'm using node v5.6.0 and bower 1.7.7 on a Mac.

I've done a `npm install` in my project folder which installs all the `/node_modules` including `q`. 
I've also done a `npm install -g q` just to see if that helped.

But as soon as I run `bower install` (or just `bower`) anywhere I get

```
ambp:~ andreaslarsen$ bower
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/bower:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem recently. I reinstalled bower globally. **npm install** and
"**npm install -g bower**" solved my problem. This downloaded the required folders in to node_modules directory globally and solved problem which I faced while installing packages with bower.

Comment: It helped me also to delete the node_modules folder and run again npm install

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I just had to restart the terminal after doing the `npm install` and before doing the `bower install`

Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem too, I tried a new terminal which didn't fix it, so I manually installed the missing module but it refused to find others, so upon further investigation it turned out to be a botched install of bower, which hadn't installed all its libs, so rerunning

```
npm install
```

fixed it for me.